# unable Showing current value in DB in a drop down box

Tags: php, oracle, html-select

I am using this code to edit.php for update database and I am using drop down box in this field but this code does not show database value. It shows drop down box only.    >>>>Select<<<<

```
<tr>
   <td><div align="right"><strong>Password&nbsp;Encrypted:</strong></div></td>
   <td>
      <select name="txtENCRYPTED">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option <?php if ($objResult["ENCRYPTED"] == "Y") {echo 'selected';} ?>value="Y">Y</option>
          <option <?php if ($objResult["ENCRYPTED"] == "N") {echo 'selected';} ?> value="N">N</option>      
      </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: where $objResult comes from ? share all your code

Comment: I can't seem to edit the tags, but the Dropbox tag does not apply to this question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <select name="txtENCRYPTED">
 <option value="Y" <?php if ($objResult["ENCRYPTED"] == "Y") echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Y</options>
 <option value="N" <?php if ($objResult["ENCRYPTED"] == "N") echo 'selected="selected"';?>>N</options>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <option <?php if ($objResult["ENCRYPTED"] == "Y") {echo 'selected';} ?>value="Y">Y</option>
```

above will result in

```
<option selected value="Y">Y</option>
```

but you need this:

```
<option selected="selected" value="Y">Y</option>
```

so change to:

```
<option value="Y" <?php if ($objResult["ENCRYPTED"] == "Y") echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Y</options>
```